# Unable to install libltc-dev in beaglebone black debian

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, make

I am trying to build some C programs in beaglebone black (using debian) which I git clone [from here.](https://github.com/x42/ltc-tools) Now I try command `make` I got this error :-

```
Makefile:9: *** "https://github.com/x42/libltc version >= 1.1.0 is required - install libltc-dev".  Stop.
```

So , I decide to install `libltc-dev` and try this

```
 apt-get install libltc-dev
```

But I got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libltc-dev
```

I google this error, but there is hardly any thing available about libltc-dev. So, can anyone tell me how to install libltc-dev.

Comment: Which version of Debian are you using? (`cat /etc/debian_version` if you don't know.)

Comment: i am using debian 7.9

Comment: libltc-dev is present in jessie (8.x) but not in wheezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`libltc`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libltc) is available in Debian 8, but not in Debian 7.

The version of the package in Debian 8 has dependencies that can all be satisfied in Debian 7 on `armhf`, so it may be possible to install that version:

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libl/libltc/libltc-dev_1.1.4-1_armhf.deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libl/libltc/libltc11_1.1.4-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libltc-dev_1.1.4-1_armhf.deb libltc11_1.1.4-1_armhf.deb
```

If that fails, the build dependencies can also all be satisfied in Debian 7, so it should be possible to build the current package using Debian 7 on your BB:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libl/libltc/libltc_1.2.0-1.dsc
cd libltc-1.2.0
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

That should produce the `.deb` files in the parent directory; you can then install them using `dpkg -i`.